# How to order ListBuffer according to another ListBuffer

Tags: scala

I have two `ListBuffer` objects:

```
val o1 = new ListBuffer[String]
val o2 = new ListBuffer[Double]
```

Both are of the same length. I want to sort `o1` according to `o2` values in descending order. This is how I try to tackle it:

```
// order `o2`
val ordered = o2.sorted(Ordering[Double].reverse)
// get indices
val ind = ordered.indices
// reorganize `o1` according to `ind`
```

First of all I don't know how to efficiently reorganize `o1` according to `ind`. Secondly I wonder if a better approach exists (maybe using map, flatMap...).
Maybe it makes sense to maintain a single data structure instead of having two ListBuffer's.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know how things moved you need to track the indicies:

```
val o3 = o2.zipWithIndex.sortBy(_._1)
```

then you can get the elements of `o1` in that order:

```
o3.map(e=>o1(e._2))  //> res0: ListBuffer(a, c, b)
```

but if you're going to do that, you might as well skip a step and incorporate the elements of `o1` before you sort:

```
(o2 zip o1).sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)  //> res1: ListBuffer(a, c, b)
```

but if the elements of `o1` and `o2` are always in lock-step, then yes, maintaining a single data structure makes sense to me

Comment: Just to point that for descending order I would need to use `(o2 zip o1).sortBy(-_._1).map(_._2)`. I.e. `sortBy(-_._1)` instead of `sortBy(_._1)`

Comment: Yes, correct. Or you can use `sorted` with an` Ordering` as in your question.  It doesn't change the basic idea, though.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this prehaps:

```
 (o1 zip o2 sortBy(-_._2) unzip)._1
```

Comment: I don't understand why the answer was downvoted??? I checked and it works perfectly.

Comment: I didn't downvote but maybe because it was missing explanation? As you say, it works...

Comment: Maybe because there is a "postfix operator unzip should be enabled" warning with the code as written.

Comment: @Phasmid really? :D Well, I have not one, but _four_ solutions for you: (1) disable the warning, (2) enable the postfix operators, (3)  rewrite the expression with spaces and parenthesis as you please, and (4) just ignore a damn warning: it's a _warning_ for a reason,  you have been warned, no further action is required. Don't obsess over the warnings, they are there to help you, not to prevent you from implementing elegant working solutions for superficial reasons.

Comment: @Dima simply trying to guess why there might have been a downvote. It wasn't _my_ downvote. Personally, I'm quite content with using any of the usual four "solutions."